# Persist VirtualHost RewriteRule in httpd.conf

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf

i have edited the httpd.conf with a RewriteRule, it looks like this:

```
    <VirtualHost myip:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias mail.mysite.com www.mysite.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
        JkMount /* mysite
        ...
```

It works fine, but when the httpd.conf is rebuilded every change i made is lost. I tried editing the pre_virtualhost_global.conf but with no success, if anybody could tell me exactly what i have to put and where i would be very grateful.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tell us something about your Environment. httpd.conf is normally not rebuilded by itself (by apache). So you (or your hoster) use some configuration tool that rebuilds the configuration. Can you name it/tag it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that there is a `pre_virtualhost_global.conf` file, so I assume that you have WHM/cPanel.  In order to modify Apache virtual hosts you have use  include files as described in WHM/cPanel's [official documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Modify+Apache+Virtual+Hosts+with+Include+Files).